# Validate or remove for extra fields in laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel

It's posible to validate request with rules for additional fields, or remove that fields from request?

Simple example, I have FormRequest object with rules:

```php
public function rules() {
        return [
            'id' => 'required|integer',
            'company_name' => 'required|max:255',
        ];
    }
```

And when I get post request with any other fields I want to get error/exception in controller or I want to get only id and company_name fields, with no any others. It's exist any feature in laravel with that, or I must make it in my way?

Comment: I am trying to understand what you want. Do you mean when a form is posted with many fields in form, say like 5 fields firstname,lastname,country, sex,age and you only want to pick out two fields ignoring others say only sex,country?

Comment: It should be first line of defense for input additional fields in form by agressor. When I have form with that 5 fields, then I want only that fields in request in server side, if anybody add any other field with value then I want to reject that request or remove that additional fields from request.

Answer (score 41):

To remove key from request in Laravel, use:

```
$request->request->remove('key')
```

Answer (score 33):

Your post request with laravel has more stuff than just your form input so you need to check Request to see what is inside.

To get only the fields you want you can use:

```
$request->only(['fieldname1', 'fieldname2', 'fieldname3']);
```

or

```
$request->except(['fieldnameYouDontWant1', 'fieldnameYouDontWant2', 'fieldnameYouDontWant3']);
```

to exclude the ones you don't want.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. I did it by override validate method in FormRequest class, but I was wondering if exist any better way?

Answer (score 21):

Since Laravel 5.5 you can do this in your controller:

```
public function store(StoreCompanyRequest $request)
{
    Company::create($request->validated());
}
```

The validated() function returns only the fields that you have validated and removes everything else.

Answer (score 6):

Starting form Laravel 5.5 you can call `validate` method right on `Request` e.g.

```
class YourController extends Controller
{

    public function store(Request $request) {

      $cleanData = $request->validate([
        'id' => 'required|integer',
        'company_name' => 'required|max:255',
      ]);

      // Now you may safely pass $cleanData right to your model
      // because it ONLY contains fields that in your rules e.g

      $yourModel->create($cleanData);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I can see this happening in L8 too, as expected, but I cannot find any source on this change. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Keep in mind that only the assigned variable will behave this way, in this case $cleanData. Your original $request object is unchanged and still contain all the original unvalidated fields.

Comment: `because it ONLY contains fields that in your rules` - I tried to find document for this without luck. Feeling frustrated with Lavarel document.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the majority of answers here have missed the point of the original issue. That being, you want to specify the fields that need validating in your FormRequest class, and then in your controller do:

`Something::create($request->validated());`

However, it might be that you want to validate a particular field, but not pass it to the `create` method in your controller.  The problem with doing `$request->only()` or `$request->except()` is that you have to repeat the fields from your FormRequest class, or repeat them in the `$guarded` property of your model.

Unfortunately the only way I found to do what you want was as follows:

`Something::create(collect($request->validated())->forget('field_you_dont_want')->toArray());`

**Edit October 2020**

Thanks to the folks over on the Laravel forum, in Laravel 7 the Request class is macroable.  So a better answer is to edit `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` and in the `boot()` method you can add:

```
// Extend the validated() method
Request::macro('validatedExcept', function($except = []) {
    return Arr::except($this->validated(), $except);
});
```

You'll need to add

`use Illuminate\Support\Arr;`

to the top of `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` too.

Then you are able to use:

```
$request->validatedExcept(['field_to_ignore', 'another_field_to_ignore']);
```

**Edit Feb 2022**

Laravel now has the `safe()` method which allows you to do this:

```
$request->safe()->except(['field_to_ignore'])
```

Or as GWidgery pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70410551/1849981) you can use the `exclude` rule:

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        'id' => 'required|integer',
        'company_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'field_to_ignore' => 'required|exclude',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Yup this is the direct answer to the question. If we are using $request->validated(), then must follow this method.

Comment: "it might be that you want to validate a particular field, but not pass it" You knock other answers for missing the point, then proceed to make up requirements that weren't in the question? It would seem to me that what you've done here could more easily be accomplished with the `exclude` validation rule.

Answer (score 4):

Things get a little trickier when you start getting into nested array element validations, especially if wildcards are involved.  Put this in your custom `Request` class, and inject it into your controller method.  Should cover all cases.

```
public function authorize()
{
    //Dot notation makes it possible to parse nested values without recursion
    $original = array_dot($this->all());
    $filtered = [];
    $rules = collect($this->rules());
    $keys = $rules->keys();
    $rules->each(function ($rules, $key) use ($original, $keys, &$filtered) {
        //Allow for array or pipe-delimited rule-sets
        if (is_string($rules)) {
            $rules = explode('|', $rules);
        }
        //In case a rule requires an element to be an array, look for nested rules
        $nestedRules = $keys->filter(function ($otherKey) use ($key) {
            return (strpos($otherKey, "$key.") === 0);
        });
        //If the input must be an array, default missing nested rules to a wildcard
        if (in_array('array', $rules) && $nestedRules->isEmpty()) {
            $key .= ".*";
        }

        foreach ($original as $dotIndex => $element) {
            //fnmatch respects wildcard asterisks
            if (fnmatch($key, $dotIndex)) {
                //array_set respects dot-notation, building out a normal array
                array_set($filtered, $dotIndex, $element);
            }
        }
    });

    //Replace all input values with the filtered set
    $this->replace($filtered);

    //If field changes were attempted, but non were permitted, send back a 403
    return (empty($original) || !empty($this->all()));
}
```

Comment: Nice solution!
I changed `$rules = explode('|', $rules);` into `if (is_string($rules)) { $rules = explode('|', $rules); }` to make it work for array-based rules as well.

Comment: Updated the snippet to include that tweak.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use except method of request which will give you fields except for the given fields

```
$request = $request->except('your_field');
```

if you want to remove multiple fields from request you can pass array of the fields

```
$request = $request->except(['field_1','field_2',...])
```

[Reference: Laravel requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests)

Comment: This does not work as expected. `$request->except` produces an array, so setting the `$request` variable causes a type change

Answer (score 3):

I have a new solution for this, create a new function in your form request class:

```
public function onlyInRules()
{
    return $this->only(array_keys($this->rules()));
}
```

Then in your controller, call `$request->onlyInRules()` instead of `$request->all()`

Answer (score 3):

This is the best way i guess

```
$this->offsetUnset('field_1');
```

in Form Request Validation you can use like this

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->offsetUnset('field_1');
}
```

Comment: Elegant, working like a charm, what I was expecting since I had to alter the request and inserting them in a variable was not an option.

Answer (score 2):

I did it by override method validate() in FormRequest class.

```php
abstract class MyFormRequest extends FormRequest {
    public function validate() {
        foreach ($this->request->all() as $key => $value) {
            if (!array_key_exists($key, $this->rules())) {
                throw new ValidationException("Field " . $key . " is not allowed.");
            }
        }
        parent::validate();
    }
}
```

I think it's not best way, but it's works. I should upgrade it to show info about all wrong fields at once :)

Comment: You can directly use $this->has('field_name') and throw exception, no need to loop through

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has an 'exclude' validation rule:
[Validation: Exclude](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-exclude)

Form Request

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'second_hand_smoke' => 'required|boolean',
        'flu_vaccination' => 'required|boolean',
        'provided' => 'required|boolean|exclude',
    ];
}
```

Controller

```
$request->validated();
```

Returns

```
array:2[
    "second_hand_smoke" => 1
    "flu_vaccination" => 1
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through your controller. You can send only two or certain fields to database. Use `$request->only()` instead of `$request->all()` and pass a array of data you want to save in database.  Your `controller`'s `store()` method should look like this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    ModelName::create($request->only(['id','company_name']));
    return redirect('RouteName');
}
```

Comment: Yes, this will work, but I want to use FormRequests for that, I dont want to specify 2nd time what should be in my form. First time I do this in FormRequest using rules, I want to reuse that rules. When you have a lot of forms in application then easy to forget about somethink.

Answer (score 0):

```
$request->validated();
```

will return only the validated data.

In your controller method:

```
public function myController(ValidationRequest $request) {
    $data = $request->validated();
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the answer for the question... see answer above...

Answer (score 0):

Since no one answered this on a "Test" perspective, what you can do is to reset the request query.

```
request()->query = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag();
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way, only for **Laravel 8**, with more functionality and verbosity:

```php
$request->safe()->all()
```

Plus, it can be easily used to search & replace `$request->all()`.