# How to remove request parameters from Form Request

Tags: php, laravel, api, lumen

How to remove request parameters in Form Request Class so in Controller it cannot access accidentally.

example:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'username' => ['required', 'string'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string'],
    ];
}

public function onlyInRules()
{
    return $this->only(array_keys($this->rules()));
}
```

Then in my controller, when I call `$request->onlyInRules()` it return right request parameters,
but `$request->all()` or `$request->paramsNotInCludedInRules` it return the value or parameters not included in rules.

I have my own reason that's why I did not use `$request->only([])` or `$request->except([])` inside controller. (cause I want to create a global function).

How to remove parameters inside Form Request Class?

Comment: Is `$request->validated()` not what you are looking for?

Comment: No, I want to discard all query string in my POST method. 
so if I `$request->all()` it will return parameters that included in rules. 
same result in `$request->validated()` and `$request->post()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validate or remove for extra fields in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35327679/validate-or-remove-for-extra-fields-in-laravel)

Comment: In my situation. I don't want to use `$request->except` or `$request->only` inside controller, I want to remove parameters in form request class that not included in rules.

Comment: [There is an answer there which shows how *To remove key from request in Laravel, use:*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45694061/6089612).  This question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Don'tPanic It's not working bro.. I used Lumen 5.8.

Comment: $request->validated() should work, or else tell us why it doesn't i have used it multiple times for exactly your case.